# Text only appears on top of webpage

Tags: html, css

I can't get my text to follow the flow of the website. It only appears on the top left of my webpage

I have tried using different positioning the the elements

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#backgroundVideo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background: url(#);
  background-size: cover;
}

.background-vid-content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay muted loop poster="#" id="backgroundVideo">
                <source src="videos/How%20To%20Cook%20A%20Cheap%20Steak%20Vs.%20An%20Expensive%20Steak%20(1).mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
<div class="background-vid-content">
  <h1>Flavor</h1>
  <p>lorem ipsumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an his etiam torquatos. Tollit soleat phaedrum te duo, eum cu recteque expetendis neglegentur. Cu mentitum maiestatis persequeris pro, pri ponderum tractatos ei. Id qui nemore latine molestiae, ad mutat oblique
    delicatissimi pro.</p>
</div>
```

I want the text to appear under the video, but it appears on the top left

Comment: Don't use `position:fixed`?

Comment: I need to use it on my video for it to scale correctly, and fill the intire screen

Comment: Your requirements are in conflict. You want a full-screen video and then content underneath it? I'm confused. Please explain what you are trying to achieve. Also, maybe confirm if you want the video to cover the entire web page or just fill the viewport. I suspect that you're looking to fill the viewport and show the text content underneath (ie, so the user has to scroll down to see it) - but this is just a guess. Please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you mean you want the text at the bottom of your video but still overlapping the video.

When doing this kind of overlapping layout the key thing is to wrap the elements you're trying to overlap in a element (usually a div) that has position set to "relative". That communicates to the browser that whatever layout happens to the children of this element should still happen relative to this element.

Then you can set position "absolute" for the element(s) you want to move, in this case your text. From there you can use the four positional CSS properties (top, right, bottom and left) to move the inner elements around.

Here is a JSFiddle to show how that can be done. https://jsfiddle.net/0mbz4fh8/1/

Relevant CSS:

```
.annotated-video {
  position: relative;
}

.annotated-video__content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

If you rather wanted the text overlay to cover the video fully and still have the text at the bottom you can do so like this. https://jsfiddle.net/0mbz4fh8/2/

Relevant CSS:

```
.annotated-video__content {
  position: absolute;
  /* Using both top and bottom stretches the container */
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* Flex is a great tool to learn, here we create a column based flex container and tell it to justify ("align" the content at the end of the column, which is the bottom) */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: This is a reasonably good answer but it seems to me that the OP wants the video as a fullscreen background to the entire webpage. Merely changing `.background-vid-content {bottom:0;}` in the code provided by the OP would net a better result. EG: https://jsfiddle.net/z7L8jdwn/3/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use position fixed. You can use `vw` and `vh` units. I included another element to wrap the video `.wrapper`. That uses `100%` width and `vh` for height to fill the screen. The video is then set to `object-fit` so it always remains full screen. I'm assuming that you wanted the description to be directly after the video. If not, the second snippet is what you want.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

#backgroundVideo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.background-vid-content {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <video autoplay muted loop poster="#" id="backgroundVideo">
  <source src="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
  <div class="background-vid-content">
    <h1>Flavor</h1>
    <p>lorem ipsumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an his etiam torquatos. Tollit soleat phaedrum te duo, eum cu recteque expetendis neglegentur. Cu mentitum maiestatis persequeris pro, pri ponderum tractatos ei. Id qui nemore latine molestiae, ad mutat oblique
      delicatissimi pro.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want the text to overlay the video, you can set the position on the `#background-vid-content` to absolute.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

#backgroundVideo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.background-vid-content {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <video autoplay muted loop poster="#" id="backgroundVideo">
  <source src="https://sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
  <div class="background-vid-content">
    <h1>Flavor</h1>
    <p>lorem ipsumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an his etiam torquatos. Tollit soleat phaedrum te duo, eum cu recteque expetendis neglegentur. Cu mentitum maiestatis persequeris pro, pri ponderum tractatos ei. Id qui nemore latine molestiae, ad mutat oblique
      delicatissimi pro.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```